# Scraping paint globs off textured drywall

Tags: drywall, painting, paint, repainting, texture

So I am not a pro painter and when I rolled my newly drywalled and orange peel textured ceiling I didn't go in a pattern.  I just rolled straight across.

There are areas where there a globs from excess paint on the side of the roller.  Needless to say, I'm going to do another coat (this will make 3) in the opposite direction in more of a pattern (I.e. No straight lines).

My question is:  how can I remove those globs without making it completely obvious that there were globs there and still preserve the orange peel (as best I can)?

Comment: Pictures would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try tapping them down with a hammer (gently!) or a wood block. They're probably fairly soft, and the more you do as far as solvents or scraping or whatever the messier your texture will get. Try the simplest, least destructive things first.

Answer (score 1):

There are solvents that will remove dried latex paint. I don't like recommending them as they are smelly and volatile but I do not think anything else will work for you. If you try to scrape them off or spackle over them you will just make a bunch of extra work.

Use a light touch with a rag to smear and blend down the globs and be prepared to apply additional coat(s) in those areas.

[image]